# Best way to save photo from URL, swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, nsurl

How to save photo? In swift 
Which way is better?

```
    @IBAction func savePhoto(_ sender: Any) {
        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImg.image!)
        let compresedImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(compresedImage!, nil, nil, nil)

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Saved", message: "Your image has been saved", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default)
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you. Used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27712427/5327882) from [Leo Dabus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2303865/leo-dabus) for the `getDataFromUrl` method to get the data from the URL:

Don't forget to add the key `Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description` to your `Info.plist` with a description to explain the user why you need access to the photo library.

[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


    func getDataFromUrl(url: URL, completion: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> ()) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            completion(data, response, error)
        }.resume()
    }


    @IBAction func savePhoto(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let yourImageURLString = "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e35/22794197_139950336649166_440006381429325824_n.jpg"

        guard let yourImageURL = URL(string: yourImageURLString) else { return }

        getDataFromUrl(url: yourImageURL) { (data, response, error) in

            guard let data = data, let imageFromData = UIImage(data: data) else { return }

            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageFromData, nil, nil, nil)
                self.imageView.image = imageFromData

                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Saved", message: "Your image has been saved", preferredStyle: .alert)
                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default)
                alert.addAction(okAction)
                self.present(alert, animated: true)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Note that saving a JPEG file data as PNG would discard its image orientation info. Btw the method looks familiar getDataFromUrl  https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/aa305b0c-0b36-4c5d-a7f8-e0648d48b3c3/view-source

Comment: Just use the original jpeg data `unwrappedData`. btw you can keep the name `guard let data = data else { return }`. and use `data` `guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else { return }`. You shouldn't recompress it. `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Indeed I used the answer to help the OP. Linked the answer

Comment: Thanks again @LeoDabus

Comment: Just use a single guard `guard let data = data, let imageFromData = UIImage(data: data) else { return }`

Comment: Hi. Thank U for reply. But in your example a static URL. But how made this code otherwise. Users paste their url and push button save.

Comment: @Woop not related to your question but `, handler: nil` and `, completion: nil` it is not required

Comment: Thanks again @LeoDabus

Comment: @Woop Just add a text field and let the user paste there the image url, after that the user hits the save button and use this url instead of the static one

Comment: @ronatory How it better to make? I didnt have such a big experience like U (((

Comment: @Woop so in your screenshot you have already a text field. Just connect it to your code like you did with your image view. Than you can access the text of the text field to use it as the url. Just try it step by step. There are enough resources available for achieving your goal if you get stuck. Just search

Comment: @ronatory Thank U you are best!

Comment: ur above code worked for me thanks and upvoted you